# Extract a List of values Filtered by criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of data some rows need to be filtered.

I have some criteria to extract those rows which I called them `crit`. For each `crit` that qualifies data, I want to get sub-set of data as output.

Sometimes there is a set of functions that can extract a group of data from a larger data set based on specific criteria that you set.
I think one of the best option would be `dplyr`. Although,  I have watched some of `dplyr` package videos they are mainly focusing on sorting and selecting of rows on some simple examples. 
Sometimes, though, we need  to be able to pull a set of criteria dynamically that change.

Thus, I need an expert consideration to `dplyr` functionality to my `data.frame`.

here is the reproducible example of my data

```
set.seed(1) 
data.list <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {
    nrep <- 3
    time <- rep(seq(90,54000,length.out=12),times=nrep) 
    Mx <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(12,-0.014,0.012),decreasing=TRUE)))
    My <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(12,-0.02,0.02),decreasing=TRUE)))
    Mz <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(12,-1,1),decreasing=TRUE)))
    df <- data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x)
})
```

from inside of this `data.list` I want to extract some unique `groups` that matches a condition.

Matching condition is defined from 
`crit` output.

```
> crit

    time         Mz       set_nbr
1 24594.55 -0.04729751    1
2 29495.45 -0.50902297    1
3 24594.55 -0.04376393    1
4 39297.27 -0.22218980    2
5 24594.55 -0.36407263    2
6 34396.36 -0.38341534    2
7 19693.64 -0.34597255    3
8 14792.73 -0.01480776    3
9 29495.45 -0.00999671    3
```

I find the first observation of negative `Mz` value inside of each `data.list` `group`. Here `group` means the values in between 90:54000 in `time` column that is one group. so each data.list[[1]] 3 group, data.list[[2]] 3 group data.list[[3]] 3 group.

I want to:

1. Find `min`, and `max` `time` value of `Mz` grouped_by `set_nbr` in the `crit` output.

**UPDATE**

with the answer of @akrun this task is done by the following code

```
  min_time<- crit %>% 
  group_by(set_nbr) %>% 
  filter(time==min(time))

  max_time<- crit %>% 
  group_by(set_nbr) %>% 
  filter(time==max(time))
```

2. Filter out these cases inside of `data.list` within the `groups`.

As for example,  inside of `data.list[[2]]` if we want to extract `min` time value of `Mz` as concluded in `crit` output

```
 > data.list[[2]]
        time      Mx            My           Mz          set_nbr
1     90.000  0.0113804381  0.0145817980  0.887449637       2
2   4990.909  0.0100259362  0.0098679308  0.772901887       2
3   9891.818  0.0050266053  0.0091723849  0.754115086       2
4  14792.727  0.0046047177  0.0045857989  0.516206105       2
5  19693.636  0.0026426272  0.0022863816  0.448997785       2
6  24594.545  0.0015677851  0.0000176389  0.423487735       2
7  29495.455 -0.0023966069 -0.0018747422  0.095293174       2
8  34396.364 -0.0027816840 -0.0018971667  0.006678971       2
9  39297.273 -0.0047251003 -0.0068489072 -0.222189800       2
10 44198.182 -0.0101464994 -0.0127653456 -0.412539690       2
11 49099.091 -0.0113172099 -0.0129949293 -0.617479780       2
12 54000.000 -0.0136599830 -0.0158004944 -0.621612755       2
13    90.000  0.0117878041  0.0158037641  0.854604177       2
14  4990.909  0.0056253446  0.0152247614  0.681014064       2
15  9891.818  0.0014885119  0.0111993956  0.565702674       2
16 14792.727  0.0009466772  0.0011852241  0.181146318       2
17 19693.636 -0.0007095856 -0.0021505871  0.033593673       2
18 24594.545 -0.0011145670 -0.0034750316 -0.364072631       2
19 29495.455 -0.0014069124 -0.0065805003 -0.433534999       2
20 34396.364 -0.0021987173 -0.0086083808 -0.462098816       2
21 39297.273 -0.0080548883 -0.0088897627 -0.464983585       2
22 44198.182 -0.0086038271 -0.0114920192 -0.562709430       2
23 49099.091 -0.0094904993 -0.0169889702 -0.779278790       2
24 54000.000 -0.0119963261 -0.0174476608 -0.798253748       2
25    90.000  0.0116124758  0.0161232645  0.922819873       2
26  4990.909  0.0101439952  0.0158178170  0.895932709       2
27  9891.818  0.0037524900  0.0142452666  0.637269377       2
28 14792.727  0.0027126828  0.0136245822  0.526445379       2
29 19693.636  0.0016400717  0.0096431459  0.435870552       2
30 24594.545  0.0015504030  0.0089490379  0.125565872       2
31 29495.455  0.0005834194  0.0057726305  0.037152275       2
32 34396.364 -0.0003232792  0.0052165649 -0.383415339       2
33 39297.273 -0.0008013126  0.0042121379 -0.487264792       2
34 44198.182 -0.0072876859 -0.0043456288 -0.637663345       2
35 49099.091 -0.0077894144 -0.0047802446 -0.741686291       2
36 54000.000 -0.0130759449 -0.0064953867 -0.799718307       2
```

we would find the output like below:

```
 > min_setnbr 2
13    90.000  0.0117878041  0.0158037641  0.854604177       2
14  4990.909  0.0056253446  0.0152247614  0.681014064       2
15  9891.818  0.0014885119  0.0111993956  0.565702674       2
16 14792.727  0.0009466772  0.0011852241  0.181146318       2
17 19693.636 -0.0007095856 -0.0021505871  0.033593673       2
18 24594.545 -0.0011145670 -0.0034750316 -0.364072631       2
19 29495.455 -0.0014069124 -0.0065805003 -0.433534999       2
20 34396.364 -0.0021987173 -0.0086083808 -0.462098816       2
21 39297.273 -0.0080548883 -0.0088897627 -0.464983585       2
22 44198.182 -0.0086038271 -0.0114920192 -0.562709430       2
23 49099.091 -0.0094904993 -0.0169889702 -0.779278790       2
24 54000.000 -0.0119963261 -0.0174476608 -0.798253748       2
```

finally, can we bind `res` outputs with ordering `set_nbr=1` `group_min`-> `group_max` ,  `set_nbr=2` `group_min`-> `group_max` ..... and so on

```
         time   Mx            My            Mz           set_nbr   group_min
##1     90.000  0.0105615570  0.0128378518  0.92123599       1         1
##2   4990.909  0.0096134025  0.0117695944  0.78439667       1         1
##3   9891.818  0.0093581318  0.0115742493  0.72867894       1         1
##4  14792.727  0.0031807426  0.0113173105  0.55464140       1         1
##5  19693.636  0.0023569651  0.0089484378  0.42502936       1         1
##6  24594.545  0.0008941874  0.0058824078 -0.04729751       1         1
##7  29495.455 -0.0043247786  0.0021214525 -0.13068103       1         1
##8  34396.364 -0.0070967748  0.0011887832 -0.20001126       1         1
##9  39297.273 -0.0086446611 -0.0009107974 -0.22002091       1         1
##10 44198.182 -0.0087562698 -0.0035490228 -0.30663302       1         1
##11 49099.091 -0.0094095244 -0.0156822550 -0.33245014       1         1
##12 54000.000 -0.0123935570 -0.0190667519 -0.34929570       1         1

        time          Mx            My          Mz         set_nbr group_max
##13     90.000  0.0105615570  0.0128378518  0.92123599       1         3
##14   4990.909  0.0096134025  0.0117695944  0.78439667       1         3
##15   9891.818  0.0093581318  0.0115742493  0.72867894       1         3
##16  14792.727  0.0031807426  0.0113173105  0.55464140       1         3
##17  19693.636  0.0023569651  0.0089484378  0.42502936       1         3
##18  24594.545  0.0008941874  0.0058824078  0.04729751       1         3
##19  29495.455 -0.0043247786  0.0021214525  0.13068103       1         3
##20  34396.364 -0.0070967748  0.0011887832 -0.20001126       1         3
##21  39297.273 -0.0086446611 -0.0009107974 -0.22002091       1         3
##22  44198.182 -0.0087562698 -0.0035490228 -0.30663302       1         3
##23  49099.091 -0.0094095244 -0.0156822550 -0.33245014       1         3
##24  54000.000 -0.0123935570 -0.0190667519 -0.34929570       1         3


 > set_nbr 2   group_min
               group_max       
 > set_nbr 3   group_min
               group_max       
    ..
```

**UPDATE**

in addition to @akrun answer, it is useful to use

```
  Rows <- x[ceiling(x$Mz-y$Mz)==0,]
```

in case of you have different length of datasets.

Comment: no answer yet? Is there any `dplyr` experts in stackoverflow?

Comment: I am a bit confused with the description.  You said `I find the first observation of negative Mz value inside of each data.list groups` and `the 24594.55 is the minimum time value of Mz and max time is 39297.273`.  Are you selecting it based on `Mz` values in `crit` and if so, I guess you are comparing it with the `Mz` column of `data.list[[2]]`?

Comment: @akrun sorry for delay. The output `data.list[[2]]` just an example. Yes I want to select minumum time and max time values of `Mz` in `crit`. The first task in this question was done with your help.

Comment: May be `lst <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {x$group <- cumsum(x$time==90);x});lst1 <- split(as.data.frame(min_time), min_time$set_nbr);> Map(function(x, y) {val <- mean(y$Mz); Rows <- x[ceiling(x$time-y$time)==0,]; val1 <- Rows$Mz-val; subset(x, group==Rows$group[which.min(val1)])}, lst, lst1)`

Comment: @akrun ok I see your point. I will explain to you. `min` time means inside of `set_nbr=2` first observation of negative value of  `Mz` time. So in this case since there are three group in `data.list[[2]]` we have to only select the one that has the smallest time (aka `min` time) that gives `Mz `  value of `-0.36407263`

Comment: As per the expected result, the `Map` code gives the output `13-24` rows of `data.list[[2]]`, `1-12` rows of `data.list[[1]]` and `13-24` of `data.list[[3]]`  Please let me if that is what you wanted

Comment: works great. I have been struggling about this problem for long time. Now its solved. Thank you very much. you can put that as an answer.  Only one thing, for `max` times I will just change the  `min_time` to `max_time` right? and can we bind them with ordering `data.list[[1]] min_time`  `data.list[[1]] max_time` +`data.list[[2]] min_time`  `data.list[[2]] max_time` ....

Comment: For `max_time`, I think that is the case. Or do you want to find the greatest difference instead of the least difference?

Comment: @akrun greatest difference is ok to me:)

Comment: So, I think you need `which.max(val1)` instead of `which.min`

Comment: @akrun Can I ask one little favor about the finalize this question. I do not have so much experience on `ggplot` can you check the end of the question.

can we plot output of `Map(function)` as shown in the graph. the right side of graph names is `set_nbr` names

Comment: Can you post that as a separate question as it will get more response?

Comment: Ok no problem. I really appriciate your guidance until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lst <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {
      x$group <- cumsum(x$time==90)
      x})
lst1 <- split(as.data.frame(min_time), min_time$set_nbr)
res <- Map(function(x, y) {
          val <- mean(y$Mz)
          Rows <- x[ceiling(x$time-y$time)==0,]
          val1 <- Rows$Mz-val
          subset(x, group==Rows$group[which.min(val1)])},
             lst, lst1)
```

Comment: Hi. just for curiosity `val<-mean(y$Mz)` here why you take the mean value of `Mz`? 

and can I add `max_time` calculation inside of `Map(function(x,y))`?

Comment: @aoronbarlow Thanks for asking that. That was one thing where I was doubtful.  I forgot to ask you about it.  When there are more than one observations, I thought `mean` would be better, but you can take the `min` or `max` value

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for explonation I understand. By the way thought I mentioned yesterday maybe you didnt catch. What about binding this `min_time` and `max_time` sets inside of one data.frame?

I added expected look at the end of the question.

Comment: @aoronbarlow  If the min_time and max_time selects different groups (ie. `x$group`), then you may need an identifier.  I would keep it as separate so that it is more clear.

Comment: @yes. I also only checked, Map(function) works correctly for min_time. I though max_time should also working. When I checked in detail I saw something is wrong.

Comment: @aoronbarlow I will check the code after sometime as I am in the middle of something

Comment: Ok I am so sorry you already mentioned it previous comment yesterday `which.max(val1)`. I apologize man!

Comment: @aoronbarlow  It's okay.  Does that fixes the problem?

Comment: yes, thanks for your great care man! I really appricate it. wish you to best!

Comment: @aoronbarlow  Also instead of `ceiling` try with `trunc`

Comment: I triend giving the same result:)

Comment: @aoronbarlow  So, is it fixed or not?

Comment: I am sorry it is fixed no problem at all.

Comment: I come to end that for my real data `the answer` gives a slightly different result because of in real `data.list` `length.out` of time values are differs. so `res` function is selecting `max_time` of rows from `data.list` those have the `Rows <- x[ceiling(x$time-y$time)==0,]` . For different length of `set_nbr` it doesnt work. How can I fix that?

Comment: @aoronbarlow Could you post that as a separate question so that it would be more clear.

Comment: @aoronbarlow How did you solve it?  Can you update it in your post